# How to config reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient to accept a self-signed cergificate?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have a server providing serval services by https. When I request these services with `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient`, I got an exception and the stack trace shown as following:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1895)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:822)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:509)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1040)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:926)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 36 more
```

I config the HttpClient as the following code

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider);
if (isUseTLS) {
    Http11SslContextSpec http11SslContextSpec = Http11SslContextSpec.forClient();
    client = client.secure(spec -> {
                spec.sslContext(http11SslContextSpec);
    });
}
```

Can I config HttpClient to accept self-signed certificate by code?
Maybe I can import cergificate into keystore by using keytool to work around, but is it possiable to solve it by coding?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE` for testing purposes. It is strongly discouraged to use this in **production**.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider);
if (isUseTLS) {
    Http11SslContextSpec http11SslContextSpec =         
            Http11SslContextSpec.forClient()
                                .configure(builder -> builder.trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE));
    client = client.secure(spec -> {
            spec.sslContext(http11SslContextSpec);
    });
}
```